# what are the protocols that bluetooth use to encrypt the data?

Tags: encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, diffie-hellman

I've been looking for the protocol that Bluetooth  (EDR and LE), use to encrypt the data. I've seen the official documentation but I don't get clear if its Diffie Hellman or E0.

PD: if I'm not wrong there are different situations in where the protocol implements one or another, i need when two devices share the 6-digits simple passkey, for example, when we pair our smartphone to a headset or to a speaker.

Comment: "the 6-digits simple passkey, for example, when we pair our smartphone to a headset or to a speaker" - I don't know how you'll enter the 6-digits passkey using your headset or speaker. Do you mean "just works" encryption instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Misplaced question

First of all, this question is not suitable to be asked on SO, as it does not involve any coding problem at all, but refers to specifications. Nevertheless, I will give you an answer.

---

### Do not mistake encryption for key exchange / generation

The `Diffie–Hellman key exchange` (or `Elliptic-Curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDH)` if operating on elliptic curves) is - as its name states - a protocol for exchanging / generating cryptographic key material. It is not about the actual data encryption nor about the actual data integrity.

`E0` on the other hand is an encryption algorithm used for actually encrypting data - but also not for authentication (integrity) of encrypted data.

### BR/EDR

Regarding BR/EDR key-exchange, authentication and encryption, you can find a nice overview in *Table 1.1: Security algorithms* in the **[BR/EDR Controller] Security Specification (Bluetooth Core Specification Version 5.2 [Vol 2] Part H [Section 1])**.

To summarize it for you, the *Security Mechanisms* `Legacy` and `Secure Simple Pairing` both use `E0` for encryption, while `Secure Connections` uses `AES-CCM`.

Note, that `Secure Simple Pairing` and `Secure Connections` both use `ECDH` for key generation, while `Legacy` uses `SAFER+`.

### LE

Encryption on the LE Link Layer is performed using `AES-CCM`, as described in **[Low Energy Controller] Low Energy Link Layer Security (Bluetooth Core Specification Version 5.2 [Vol 6] Part E)**.

The actual encryption on the Link Layer needs some cryptographic keys, which are derived / calculated during pairing using the methods described in the **[Host] Security Manager Specification (Bluetooth Core Specification Version 5.2 [Vol 3] Part H)**.

To summarize it for you, there are `LE legacy pairing` (Short Term Key (STK) Generation) and `LE Secure Connections` (Long Term Key (LTK) Generation).

Note that both are about key-generation / exchange, while `LE legacy pairing` uses (somehow) `AES` and `LE Secure Connections` uses `ECDH`.